# Angularjs typescript migration

Tags: angularjs, typescript, systemjs, typescript1.5

I have a fairly sizeable angularjs application that I will eventually migrate to Angular 2.

I want to to take whatever steps I can now to make future migration easier.

I am converting my controllers and services to typescript and organising my files in a component-oriented folder structure.

What I would really like to be able to do is use es6 style module loading.

I understand that system.js can provide the loading functionality now and I can use es6 import syntax in typescript 1.5.

My question is, how should I use the two together? Should I output es6 modules from typescript and use system.js module loading with the generated code? Or is some other step required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I output es6 modules from typescript and use system.js module loading with the generated code

I would output `commonjs` modules and then use System.js at the moment. Note that `System.js` module output is going to arrive in TypeScript 1.6. See roadmap : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#16

Comment: How about outputting AMD basarat? Is there an advantage over commonjs?

Comment: You get to use it in node (as is)

Comment: This is a browser only angular app. I don't think I need to think about commonjs. Am I right?

Comment: You might want to test portions with node. Also you might want to use modules from NPM

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using commonjs since there are lot of node modules already written using that. The problem with using es6 modules is a large number of browsers are not going to support es6 modules for a long time.